# Code deleting from datagrid but not in database

Tags: c#

My code works in deleting information from the datagrid but does not delete it from the actual database. I am not sure how to fix this. Can i have some assistance please.

```
    MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection();
    MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand();
    DataTable sqlData = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter SqlAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet sqlSet = new DataSet();
    MySqlDataReader sqlDataReader;
    
    //int dmlInfo;
    String queried;
    String server = "localhost";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "";
    String database = "premiercare";
        
        sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;

        //removes from database (work to be done)
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "Delete from premiercare.addpatient where id = @id";
        sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(queried, sqlConnection);
        sqlConnection.Close();


        //removes from dataGrid
        foreach (DataGridViewRow items in this.dgAddPat.SelectedRows)
        {
            dgAddPat.Rows.RemoveAt(items.Index);
        }

        foreach (Control con in gbAddPat.Controls)
        {
            if (con is TextBox)
                ((TextBox)con).Clear();
        }

        loadInfo();
    }
```

Comment: Where is the id parameter set?

Comment: You are constructing a new instance of `MySqlCommand` after you set the previous instance `CommandText` property. You set `sqlCommand.CommandText = "Delete from premiercare.addpatient where id = @id";` and then you assign a new instance to `sqlCommand` => `sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(queried, sqlConnection);` Where is `queried` coming from? Also `sqlConnection.Close();` what do you think this is doing? You're not executing your query either: `sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`... Set some breakpoints, it will help you figure out where your issues start.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure the connection and the queryString are correct and then you could do it like this:

```
    //todo: make sure the connectionString is right
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //todo: build the right queryString
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    //no need to close the connection because of "using"
```

Comment: i believe the connection string is right. It works for inserting data and updating data from the datagrid and database.
To be honest I am new to visual studio and c# so the code I am writing was instructed by the professor, which worked for everything else but deleting data so I am unsure of how to begin to fix the issue.

Comment: I get it and don't worry, you will get it running. As I can see you added more information to the code now. 
The main issue right now is that you are not executing the (right) query. 

You close the connection before calling "sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();" - that is missing. 
You also instantiate the "sqlCommand" twice - first you set the command text but as soon as you call

` sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(queried, sqlConnection);`

 the information on the SqlCommand will be gone.